# Div not containing text properly

Tags: html, css

Without moving around any HTML how do I fix the problem I am having with the [#wrapper #banner .banner_box](http://brandroot.com/free-business-name-ideas) on this page and a lot of others like it. I've tried setting the height to auto and displaying the banner as block but it remains the same size. I want it to encompass all the text and video inside of it without setting a fixed height to it.

Comment: can we see your code

Comment: You can see the code using any web developer tool in a browser. there is way too much associated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to add another `<div class="clr"></div>` within `#banner` just before closing it

This will insure the height of the element `#banner` maintains the height of it's children with `clear: both;`

---

If you want a pure CSS solution.

Just add `overflow: auto;` to the element`#banner` (the one not maintaining it's height)

Also, in your case.. should add it to `#wrapper #banner .banner_box` with a little extra padding bottom.

```
#wrapper #banner .banner_box {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 972px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Now it will resize itself to the proper height.

Comment: I can't move any HTML around right now. It's too complex.

Comment: Just add an additional `div.clr` just before the closing of `#banner`

Comment: It's the very common way of solving this issue, and one of the conveniences of using a `clear` div

Comment: I already tested it in my browser, it works :)

Comment: I already see a clear div at the end of banner.

Comment: Actually what you're seeing is one after the closing `div`, place another one just before the div closes

Comment: Right after you close `.banner_box`

Comment: I see. Well the problem is I have no clue where to find this file to change. The site is an extremely complex Joomla site. doing a search for the tag pulls up tons of files.

Comment: Kind of hard to debug your code for you if you cant change it :)

Comment: I can change CSS, which I mentioned in the question. I'm not the developer so I'm looking for a quick fix until the develop is back Monday.

Comment: Thank I did just that. I'll apply your suggestion for clear when the developer can do it. I appreciate it.

Comment: I figured it out! :) `#wrapper #banner {overflow: auto;}` to your css and walla!

Comment: That contained the text but for some reason not the video

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `float:left` from line 338 of template.css, then add this style:

```
.custom_find{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: That worked but it still doesn't contain the video.